# Not Able to import PIL in Sikuli

Tags: python, sikuli

I want to import PIL in Sikuli for doing that I have added the code below

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Python27\Lib\site-packages")
sys.path.append("C:\\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL")

import PIL
import Image
```

So it imported the above modules but when I am trying to import ImageFont, it's giving me the error below:

```
def getmask2(self, text, mode="", fill=Image.core.fill):
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 39, in __getattr__
raise ImportError("The _imaging C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed
```

I am able to import PIL and Image and ImageFont successfully in Python scripts and code is running fine.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It appears that the C library part of PIL wasn't installed. How did you install PIL?

Comment: I used PIL-fork-1.1.7.win-amd64-py2.7 binary to install PIL from this site : http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sikuli IDE uses Jython so packages installed to your local Python version won't be able to be imported within the Sikuli IDE and Jython doesn't support c extensions as far I'm aware which PIL requires ( see  http://bugs.jython.org/issue1388 ).

I think you would need to use a Java library, maybe something like ImageJ ( see  http://fiji.sc/wiki/index.php/Jython_Scripting )

Comment: Thanks, I used Java libs to play with Images and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Since the following (as I think valuable information) was rejected as an edit to the original question (my intention: people should see this in the first place), I put it as an answer now:

I want to add:
Python modules can be imported in Jython/Sikuli scripts as long as they contain only Python code. There are many modules written for Python, that hold this condition (e.g. xlrd, xlwt). But as correctly mentioned: PIL contains C-based stuff and this can normally (exception JNI libs) not be loaded (hence the above error message, which is true, but might lead in the wrong direction).