# How can I import a Python script with several modules included into Sikuli

Tags: python, sikuli

I'm trying to call a Python (2.7) script from Sikuli (r930) and use a variable from the script. Below is the Python code:

```
import sys
import re
import os
import time
from pywinauto import application
from SendKeys import SendKeys
from cStringIO import StringIO


app=application.Application()
app.connect_(path=r'C:\Program Files\myApp\myApp.exe')

backup = sys.stdout

sys.stdout = StringIO()     

app.dlg.print_control_identifiers()

out = sys.stdout.getvalue() 

sys.stdout.close()  # close the stream 
sys.stdout = backup # restore original stdout

regex = re.compile(r'(\d{8}\s*\-\s*\d{8})')
found = re.search(regex, out)

print found.group(0) #pass this variable to Sikuli
```

I'm capturing `stdout` because this is what [Pywinauto's](http://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) `print_control_identifiers` method returns (not a string). Also, I need a hashed serial number from the GUI app that I can't get with Sikuli, hence the need to use Pywinauto. However, when I attempt to call `execfile()` from Sikuli, I get the error:

```
ImportError: no module named Pywinauto.
```

I read the docs, and I know that Sikuli (Jython) can include Python modules and scripts. Besides, the external .py file that I'm calling runs successfully when ran independently. Can someone tell me if I'm missing a step?

Code I'm using to call the .py file shown above from Sikuli:

```
aScript = 'c:\\getHash_serial.py'
execfile(aScript)
```

Comment: Hi Suffa, please read about the same problem with PIL module - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488117/not-able-to-import-pil-in-sikuli?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem you're having is that Jython can't find your module.  Probably, you installed it under Python, and they don't share a module path.  You can fix this by setting the [JYTHONPATH](http://www.jython.org/docs/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables) environment variable.

However, Pywinauto links with native code, and this is something that Jython does not support.

You may be able to get around this limitation by calling regular Python from Jython via the [subprocess module](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/subprocess.html).