# jython: how to crop a png image file

Tags: png, jython, crop

I tried PIL (Python Image Library). Unfortunately, jython doesn't support it.

```
import Image
im = Image.open("tmp.png")
box = (100,200,300,400)
region = im.crop(box)
```

And the error message is

```
  File "dota\PIL\Image.py", line 37, in __getattr__
    raise ImportError("The _imaging C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed
```

Is there other way?

Comment: Looks like there's a useful explanation and suggestion on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488117/not-able-to-import-pil-in-sikuli